# Functions on finite metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces

Is a function f from a finite metric space M to itself always continuous? I have tried proving it, but I have gotten stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where, exactly, did you get stuck? What definition of "continuous" are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: If $M$ is a finite metric space, then which subsets of $M$ are open?

Comment: Can I call this a discrete [sic] hint?

Comment: Certainly, that is within your power.

Comment: Your pun was much better than mine....

Comment: It occurred to me after I left the comment that a wonderful answer would be, in its entirety: HINT: Let me offer a discrete [sic] hint.